# can't get model attributes to persist in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a bunch of reviews in my console created by a Review.rb model, which has a boolean attribute 'finished' to indicate whether the review is complete.  In my development database, the finished attribute of every review is currently set to 'true,' which I did through the UI. However, I now want, using the console, to set the finished attribute back to its original setting (nil), so that I can experiment with something in the UI. Therefore, I did this in the Rails console.

```
>> Review.all.each do |s|
?> s.finished = nil
>> end
```

The output of running this showed that 'finished' was being set to nil. However,  when I queried Review.all again, the attribute finished was still set to 'true.'  I'm guessing I have to save this somehow, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save` objects:

```
   >> Review.all.each do |s|
   ?> s.finished = nil
   ?> s.save!
   >> end
```

Or:

```
 Review.update_all(:finished => nil)  #in one line
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to save the whole block to a variable and save it. Duh.

Comment: +1 for Review.update_all(:finished => nil), thats the way to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
Review.all.each do |s|
      s.finished = nil
      s.save!
end
```

or try to call `Review.save_all` at the end